# Rename Downloaded Files Inside Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, download, rename

I'm using Google Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit) on OS X El-Capitan version 10.11.3 (15D21), and happen to download a lot of files everyday.

Now, once I download them from source A, I need to rename **some of them** and upload them to destination B.

Problem is - I have to go into the download folder, change the file name, and then upload it each and every time.

Is there a way to rename files inside the browser (inside the little bar that opens in the bottom when you download a file) without enabling the "rename after download" feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to chrome settings (you may type in address bar `chrome://settings/`)

Search `ask where` on the right hand box

Tick the option `Ask where to save each file before downloading`

[image]

Next time when you download the file, you can edit the file name if needed
[image]